# URL rewriting without redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting, address-bar

I have a couple of directives which should redirect the user to the right path:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ user?user=$1 [QSA]
```

So that writing `www.mywebsite.com/myprofile` it displays `www.mywebsite.com/user?user=myprofile`

It works properly, but it redirects to that URL.

What I would like is that my browser displayed `www.mywebsite.com/user?user=myprofile` (which is an existing folder on my server), but still showed `www.mywebsite.com/myprofile` on the address bar, which is the way many websites (*as far as I know*) create your own profile page.

How is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try just as this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ user/?user=$1 [QSA]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ user/index.php?user=$1 [QSA]
```

With the slash added, the URL is not redirected by only rewritten.

Comment: Thank you very much! One last thing: is there a way to access the original URL from the backend (for example using PHP)?

Comment: @Foxel originally requested URL should be in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`